# Python: reading 12-bit binary files

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, unpack

I am trying to read 12-bit binary files containing images (a video) using Python 3.

To read a similar file but encoded in 16 bits, the following works very well:

```
import numpy as np
images = np.memmap(filename_video, dtype=np.uint16, mode='r', shape=(nb_frames, height, width))
```

where filename_video is the file and nb_frames, height, and width characteristics of the video that can be read from another file. By 'working very well' I mean fast: reading a 640x256 video that has 140 frames takes about 1 ms on my computer.

As far as I know I cannot use this when the file is encoded in 12 bits because there is no uint12 type. So what I am trying to do is to read a 12-bit file and store it in a 16-bit uint array. The following, taken from ([Python: reading 12 bit packed binary image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797779/python-reading-12-bit-packed-binary-image)), works:

```
with open(filename_video, 'rb') as f:
    data=f.read()
images=np.zeros(int(2*len(data)/3),dtype=np.uint16)
ii=0
for jj in range(0,int(len(data))-2,3):
    a=bitstring.Bits(bytes=data[jj:jj+3],length=24)
    images[ii],images[ii+1] = a.unpack('uint:12,uint:12')
    ii=ii+2
images = np.reshape(images,(nb_frames,height,width))
```

However, this is very slow: reading a 640x256 video thas has only 5 frames takes about 11.5 s with my machine. Ideally I would like to be able to read 12-bit files as efficiently as I can read 8 or 16-bit files using memmap. Or at least not 10^5 times slower. How could I speed things up ?

Here is a file example:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=26973488795334213426
(nb_frames=5, height=256, width=640).

Comment: that's very cool (+1). I only knew about like OpenCV's `cv.cvtColor(bayer,rgb,cv.COLOR_BayerBG2BGR)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have a slightly different implementation from the one proposed by @max9111 that doesn't require a call to `unpackbits`.

It creates two `uint12` values from three consecutive `uint8` directly by cutting the middle byte in half and using numpy's binary operations. In the following, `data_chunks` is assumed to be a binary string containing the information for an arbitrary number number of 12-bit integers (hence its length must be a multiple of 3).

```
def read_uint12(data_chunk):
    data = np.frombuffer(data_chunk, dtype=np.uint8)
    fst_uint8, mid_uint8, lst_uint8 = np.reshape(data, (data.shape[0] // 3, 3)).astype(np.uint16).T
    fst_uint12 = (fst_uint8 << 4) + (mid_uint8 >> 4)
    snd_uint12 = ((mid_uint8 % 16) << 8) + lst_uint8
    return np.reshape(np.concatenate((fst_uint12[:, None], snd_uint12[:, None]), axis=1), 2 * fst_uint12.shape[0])
```

I benchmarked with the other implementation and this approach proved to be ~4x faster on a ~5 Mb input:
`read_uint12_unpackbits` 65.5 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
`read_uint12` 14 ms ± 513 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Answer (score 9):

One way to speedup the numpy-vectorized methods is to avoid costly memory allocations for temporary data, use cache more efficently and make use of parallelization. This can be quite easily be done using `Numba`, `Cython` or `C`. Please note that the parallelization is not always beneficial. If the array you want to convert is too small, use the single threaded version (`parallel=False`)

**Numba version of Cyril Gaudefroy answer with temporary memory allocation**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.njit(nb.uint16[::1](nb.uint8[::1]),fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def nb_read_uint12(data_chunk):
  """data_chunk is a contigous 1D array of uint8 data)
  eg.data_chunk = np.frombuffer(data_chunk, dtype=np.uint8)"""
  
  #ensure that the data_chunk has the right length
  assert np.mod(data_chunk.shape[0],3)==0
  
  out=np.empty(data_chunk.shape[0]//3*2,dtype=np.uint16)
  
  for i in nb.prange(data_chunk.shape[0]//3):
    fst_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3])
    mid_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3+1])
    lst_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3+2])
    
    out[i*2] =   (fst_uint8 << 4) + (mid_uint8 >> 4)
    out[i*2+1] = ((mid_uint8 % 16) << 8) + lst_uint8
    
  return out
```

**Numba version of Cyril Gaudefroy answer with memory preallocation**

If you apply this function multiple times on data-chunks of simmilar size you can preallocate the output array only once.

```
@nb.njit(nb.uint16[::1](nb.uint8[::1],nb.uint16[::1]),fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def nb_read_uint12_prealloc(data_chunk,out):
    """data_chunk is a contigous 1D array of uint8 data)
    eg.data_chunk = np.frombuffer(data_chunk, dtype=np.uint8)"""

    #ensure that the data_chunk has the right length
    assert np.mod(data_chunk.shape[0],3)==0
    assert out.shape[0]==data_chunk.shape[0]//3*2

    for i in nb.prange(data_chunk.shape[0]//3):
        fst_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3])
        mid_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3+1])
        lst_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3+2])

        out[i*2] =   (fst_uint8 << 4) + (mid_uint8 >> 4)
        out[i*2+1] = ((mid_uint8 % 16) << 8) + lst_uint8

    return out
```

**Numba version of DGrifffith answer with temporary memory allocation**

```
@nb.njit(nb.uint16[::1](nb.uint8[::1]),fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def read_uint12_var_2(data_chunk):
    """data_chunk is a contigous 1D array of uint8 data)
    eg.data_chunk = np.frombuffer(data_chunk, dtype=np.uint8)"""

    #ensure that the data_chunk has the right length
    assert np.mod(data_chunk.shape[0],3)==0

    out=np.empty(data_chunk.shape[0]//3*2,dtype=np.uint16)

    for i in nb.prange(data_chunk.shape[0]//3):
        fst_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3])
        mid_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3+1])
        lst_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3+2])

        out[i*2] =   (fst_uint8 << 4) + (mid_uint8 >> 4)
        out[i*2+1] = (lst_uint8 << 4) + (15 & mid_uint8)

    return out
```

**Numba version of DGrifffith answer with memory preallocation**

```
@nb.njit(nb.uint16[::1](nb.uint8[::1],nb.uint16[::1]),fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def read_uint12_var_2_prealloc(data_chunk,out):
    """data_chunk is a contigous 1D array of uint8 data)
    eg.data_chunk = np.frombuffer(data_chunk, dtype=np.uint8)"""

    #ensure that the data_chunk has the right length
    assert np.mod(data_chunk.shape[0],3)==0
    assert out.shape[0]==data_chunk.shape[0]//3*2

    for i in nb.prange(data_chunk.shape[0]//3):
        fst_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3])
        mid_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3+1])
        lst_uint8=np.uint16(data_chunk[i*3+2])

        out[i*2] =   (fst_uint8 << 4) + (mid_uint8 >> 4)
        out[i*2+1] = (lst_uint8 << 4) + (15 & mid_uint8)

    return out
```

**Timings**

```
num_Frames=10
data_chunk=np.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=np.int(640*256*1.5*num_Frames),dtype=np.uint8)

%timeit read_uint12_gaud(data_chunk)
#11.3 ms ± 53.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#435 MB/s

%timeit nb_read_uint12(data_chunk)
#939 µs ± 24.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#5235 MB/s

out=np.empty(data_chunk.shape[0]//3*2,dtype=np.uint16)
%timeit nb_read_uint12_prealloc(data_chunk,out)
#407 µs ± 5.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#11759 MB/s

%timeit read_uint12_griff(data_chunk)
#10.2 ms ± 55.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
#491 MB/s

%timeit read_uint12_var_2(data_chunk)
#928 µs ± 16.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#5297 MB/s
%timeit read_uint12_var_2_prealloc(data_chunk,out)
#403 µs ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#12227 MB/s
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for the tip with numba. I had similar issues with computation time needed for the conversion. I tried it with bitArray and bitString package but than looping was simply too slow. Implementing it in your most recently suggested way did it! Again, thank's, great answer.

Comment: Hey @max9111, This is a great answer, could you advise on modifying this numba operation for the answer below (it uses a different packing/bit order). This would be super useful!

Comment: @Gittb Which one do you mean (username)? The ordering of the answers may differ. (I see my answer as the last one) Yes, but not today. At the weekend.

Comment: The solution by the username @DGrifffith 

No rush on the time. I appreciate your help. If you could ping me when you worked it that would be awesome.

Comment: Thank you Max, I really appreciate this!!

Answer (score 3):

Found @cyrilgaudefroy answer useful. However, initially, it did not work on my 12-bit packed binary image data. Found out that the packing is a bit different in this particular case. The "middle" byte contained the least significant nibbles. Bytes 1 and 3 of the triplet are the most significant 8 bits of the twelve. Hence modified @cyrilgaudefroy answer to:

```
def read_uint12(data_chunk):
    data = np.frombuffer(data_chunk, dtype=np.uint8)
    fst_uint8, mid_uint8, lst_uint8 = np.reshape(data, (data.shape[0] // 3, 3)).astype(np.uint16).T
    fst_uint12 = (fst_uint8 << 4) + (mid_uint8 >> 4)
    snd_uint12 = (lst_uint8 << 4) + (np.bitwise_and(15, mid_uint8))
    return np.reshape(np.concatenate((fst_uint12[:, None], snd_uint12[:, None]), axis=1), 2 * fst_uint12.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another variation. My data format is:

first uint12: most significant 4 bits from least significant 4 bits of second uint8 + least significant 8 bits from first uint8

second uint12: most significant 8 bits from third uint8 + least significant 4 bits from most significant 4 bits from second uint8

The corresponding code is:

```
def read_uint12(data_chunk):
    data = np.frombuffer(data_chunk, dtype=np.uint8)
    fst_uint8, mid_uint8, lst_uint8 = np.reshape(data, (data.shape[0] // 3, 3)).astype(np.uint16).T
    fst_uint12 = ((mid_uint8 & 0x0F) << 8) | fst_uint8
    snd_uint12 = (lst_uint8 << 4) | ((mid_uint8 & 0xF0) >> 4)
    return np.reshape(np.concatenate((fst_uint12[:, None], snd_uint12[:, None]), axis=1), 2 * fst_uint12.shape[0])
```

Comment: This variant worked for me as well. It matches Matlab's `ubit12` representation.