# Reading a structured binary file with numpy: fromfile vs. read & frombuffer

Tags: python, performance, numpy, binaryfiles

I’m reading a binary file using `numpy` and wondering whether I should use repeated calls to [`numpy.fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) or reading from the file manually and calling [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html):

```
# Alternative 1: fromfile
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    num = numpy.fromfile(f, 'u4', 1)[0]
    l = numpy.fromfile(f, 'u4', num)
    o = numpy.fromfile(f, 'u4', num)
    m = numpy.fromfile(f, 'f4', num)
    c = numpy.fromfile(f, '3f4', num)
    s = numpy.fromfile(f, '3u4', num)

# Alternative 2: read & frombuffer
def fread(f, fmt):
    dtype = numpy.dtype(fmt)
    return numpy.frombuffer(f.read(dtype.itemsize), dtype)[0]
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    num = fread(f, 'u4')
    l = fread(f, f'({num},)u4')
    o = fread(f, f'({num},)u4')
    m = fread(f, f'({num},)f4')
    c = fread(f, f'({num},3)f4')
    s = fread(f, f'({num},3)u4')
```

Is there a difference (performance or otherwise) between these two methods?

Comment: Why don't you just measure runtime and compare ? Either use `time.time` or install `line_profiler` for this.

Comment: @rocksportrocker “performance or otherwise”

Comment: You should probably read and link to the docs for both functions.  Those should describe any major differences in behavior.

Comment: @user2699 Unfortunately, I have found that many `numpy` functions are rather poorly documented (in that they don’t explain what the function actually *does*, rather giving a small number of examples instead of a specification of behavior), these two included. `numpy.frombuffer`: “*Interpret a buffer as a 1-dimensional array.*” `numpy.fromfile`: “*Construct an array from data in a text or binary file. A highly efficient way of reading binary data with a known data-type, as well as parsing simply formatted text files. Data written using the tofile method can be read using this function.*”

Comment: @Socob, the doc's aren't always the clearest but they're usually the best place to start.  For instance from the docs for these functions it's clear that `fromfile` will handle text data while `frombuffer` only works with binary data.  It also suggests that `frombuffer` doesn't make a copy of the underlying data.

Comment: Both functions are compiled, so we can't easily study their code.  `fromfile` probably does something like your `fread`. That is, use a Python call call to read a block of the file, and then use the same sort of `frombuffer` logic or code to parse it.  You might save time by doing one `f.read` to load the whole buffer, and then use `frombuffer` with offsets.  But the disk reads are probably already cached at a lower level.

Comment: For larger chunks (num) and standard datatypes I would definitely prefer the first aproach. In case of quite small chunks (where acess latency does play a role) or non standard dtypes eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070947/4045774, I would prefer reading a raw-datachunk (a few MB) in memory and process it afterwards (-> a modified version of the second aproach)