# How to do fast bitwise operations on a scalar with the `cupy` library

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I am building a reinforcement learning model on the GPU, so I am using [chainer](https://chainer.org/) which has the [cupy](https://cupy.chainer.org/) backend.  `cupy` is intended to be a duplicate of `numpy` except that it operates on the GPU.

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782511/why-is-numpy-slower-than-python-for-left-bit-shifts) earlier on how to do fast bit shifting on a scalar in `numpy`, and the answer was easy: I need to do my bit shifting on the actual `numpy.uint64` object and not on a `numpy.array` object.  It would be nice if I could transfer my bit shifting methods over to `cupy` to get the same speedups.

However, `cupy` documentation requires that scalars be on the GPU instead of the CPU ([source](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/difference.html#zero-dimensional-array)).  This means that either I...

1. represent my scalar as an array, which brings up my original problem in my linked question above, or
2. push my scalar integer to the CPU, do my computations, and push it back to the GPU, which is also slow.

If I want to do hundreds of thousands of bit-shifts on a scalar value, although this would take less than a second in `numpy`, this takes way too long in `cupy`.  **How do I speed up bit shifting of scalars in `cupy`?**

Comment: Shifting a single scalar boxed in an array is slow, but if you put hundreds of thousands of scalars in an array and bitshift it will be fast.  Do you have to do the shifts one at a time?

Comment: Yes, I cannot batch my bit shifts.  They must be done one at a time.