# How to optimize binary file manipulation?

Tags: python, python-bytearray

here is my code:

```
def decode(filename):

    with open(filename, "rb") as binary_file:
        # Read the whole file at once
        data = bytearray( binary_file.read())

    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] = 0xff - data[i]

    with open("out.log", "wb") as out:
        out.write(data)
```

I have a file around 10MB, and I need to translate this file by flipping every bits, and save it to a new file.

It takes around 1 second using my code to translate a 10MB file, while it only takes less than 1ms using C.

This is my first python script. I don't if it is right to use bytearray. The most time consuming code is loop for bytearray.

Comment: You don't have to loop expclicitly over the array, this is very slow in pure Python. eg. data=0xff - data is engough (without any explicit loop). Another alternative is to use an compiler like Numba (LLVM based quite like Clang and Flang). Example on bitshifting using Numba: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070947/4045774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using using the `numpy` library is an option, then using it would be *much*<sup>**★**</sup> faster since it can perform the operation on all the bytes via a single statement. Doing byte-level operations in pure Python to relatively large amoont of data is inherently going to be relatively slow as compared to using a module like `numpy` which is implemented in C and optimized for array processing.

<sup>**★** Although not by quite as much in Python 2 as in 3 (see results below).</sup>

The following is a framework I set up to benchmark using it vs the code in your question. It may seem like a lot of code, but most of it is just part of the scaffolding for making performance comparisons.

I encourage others answering this question to also make use of it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import namedtuple
import os
import sys
from random import randrange
from textwrap import dedent
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import timeit
import traceback


N = 1  # Number of executions of each "algorithm".
R = 3  # Number of repetitions of those N executions.

UNITS = 1024 * 1024  # MBs
FILE_SIZE = 10 * UNITS

# Create test files. Must be done here at module-level to allow file
# deletions at end.
with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb', delete=False) as inp_file:
    FILE_NAME_IN = inp_file.name
    print('Creating temp input file: "{}", length {:,d}'.format(FILE_NAME_IN, FILE_SIZE))
    inp_file.write(bytearray(randrange(256) for _ in range(FILE_SIZE)))

with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb', delete=False) as out_file:
    FILE_NAME_OUT = out_file.name
    print('Creating temp output file: "{}"'.format(FILE_NAME_OUT))


# Common setup for all testcases (executed prior to any Testcase specific setup).
COMMON_SETUP = dedent("""
    from __main__ import FILE_NAME_IN, FILE_NAME_OUT
""")

class Testcase(namedtuple('CodeFragments', ['setup', 'test'])):
    """ A test case is composed of separate setup and test code fragments. """
    def __new__(cls, setup, test):
        """ Dedent code fragment in each string argument. """
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (dedent(setup), dedent(test)))

testcases = {
    "user3181169": Testcase("""
        def decode(filename, out_filename):
            with open(filename, "rb") as binary_file:
                # Read the whole file at once
                data = bytearray(binary_file.read())

            for i in range(len(data)):
                data[i] = 0xff - data[i]

            with open(out_filename, "wb") as out:
                out.write(data)

        """, """
        decode(FILE_NAME_IN, FILE_NAME_OUT)
        """
    ),

    "using numpy": Testcase("""
        import numpy as np

        def decode(filename, out_filename):
            with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                data = np.frombuffer(file.read(), dtype=np.uint8)

            # Applies mathematical operation to entire array.
            data = 0xff - data

            with open(out_filename, "wb") as out:
                out.write(data)
        """, """
        decode(FILE_NAME_IN, FILE_NAME_OUT)
        """,
    ),
}

# Collect timing results of executing each testcase multiple times.
try:
    results = [
        (label,
         min(timeit.repeat(testcases[label].test,
                           setup=COMMON_SETUP + testcases[label].setup,
                           repeat=R, number=N)),
        ) for label in testcases
    ]
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)  # direct output to stdout
    sys.exit(1)

# Display results.
major, minor, micro = sys.version_info[:3]
bitness = 64 if sys.maxsize > 2**32 else 32
print('Fastest to slowest execution speeds using ({}-bit) Python {}.{}.{}\n'
      '({:,d} execution(s), best of {:d} repetition(s)'.format(
            bitness, major, minor, micro, N, R))
print()

longest = max(len(result[0]) for result in results)  # length of longest label
ranked = sorted(results, key=lambda t: t[1]) # ascending sort by execution time
fastest = ranked[0][1]
for result in ranked:
    print('{:>{width}} : {:9.6f} secs, relative speed: {:6,.2f}x, ({:8,.2f}% slower)'
          ''.format(
                result[0], result[1], round(result[1]/fastest, 2),
                round((result[1]/fastest - 1) * 100, 2),
                width=longest))

# Clean-up.
for filename in (FILE_NAME_IN, FILE_NAME_OUT):
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Output (Python 3):

```
Creating temp input file: "T:\temp\tmpw94xdd5i", length 10,485,760
Creating temp output file: "T:\temp\tmpraw4j4qd"
Fastest to slowest execution speeds using (32-bit) Python 3.7.1
(1 execution(s), best of 3 repetition(s)

using numpy :  0.017744 secs, relative speed:   1.00x, (    0.00% slower)
user3181169 :  1.099956 secs, relative speed:  61.99x, (6,099.14% slower)
```

Output (Python 2):

```
Creating temp input file: "t:\temp\tmprk0njd", length 10,485,760
Creating temp output file: "t:\temp\tmpvcaj6n"
Fastest to slowest execution speeds using (32-bit) Python 2.7.15
(1 execution(s), best of 3 repetition(s)

using numpy :  0.017930 secs, relative speed:   1.00x, (    0.00% slower)
user3181169 :  0.937218 secs, relative speed:  52.27x, (5,126.97% slower)
```

Comment: Good work. decode take 10s, decode2 take 10ms. writing byte per byte is not the good way. mmap doesn't accelerate vs direct read().

Comment: @B.M.: Thanks. You're absolutely right about `mmap` not helping, so I removed that to one only using `numpy` (and added fairly generic code to do benchmark different approaches).